# Rainbird emitters not emitting water

Tags: sprinkler-system, irrigation

Im adding a drip system to my backyard garden and plants. I’m adding rainbird emitters, both half gallon per hour and one gallon per hour. When I turn on the water though, no water is emitted through the emitters.

I’ve added a video showing that when I unkink the end of the netaphim hose the water sprays outs quite a bit.

https://youtube.com/shorts/zk4cEAOCN40?feature=share

Any ideas on how I can get my emitters to emit water? I have about thirty emitters connected and sometimes when I turn off the water some of the lower emitters start emitting.

Comment: what is the size of the feeding line

Comment: @knowitall the tubing is 1/4”

Comment: I meant the big one

Comment: I would say close to an inch

Comment: My neighbor just came over and he uncorked one of the emitters and then the rest of them started flowing

Comment: interesting, ignore my answer then

Comment: But when he uncorked the emitter the water was off. When the water is in it doesn’t emit anymore

Comment: are the emitters installed backwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your video, you installed the emitters the wrong way.
It should be opposite

[image: emitter]

The emitter has two ends

One with pointy end and one not.

You do not need the additional connector at 1/2 inch hose.

Attach the emitter to the 1/4 hose (on the colored part), then use to other end of the emitter (the pointy one) to puncture the larger hose. So the emitter sits on the large hose and the 1/4 inch hose goes where you want it to drip.

[image: punch]